# Why applying sizeof operator to an extern variable does not output 0

Tags: c

The output of the following code is `4`.
Shouldn't it be `0`?

Since a is declared and not been defined and hence memory is not allocated for it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    extern int a;
    printf("%ld",sizeof(a));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have printed the size, which is 4 bytes and not 0 byte

Comment: What can you know from the declaration `int a` ? It is an integer. Is the size of an integer fixed? Yes.

Comment: BTW, `sizeof` returns `size_t` and the correct format specifier for it is `%zu`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two points:

1. `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, not run time<sup>1</sup>.  It doesn't depend on when `a` has actually been allocated.  This is because...
2. `sizeof` operates on *types*, not objects.  When the operand is an object expression like `a`, the *type* of that expression is used.  Again, this is all done at compile time, when the type of an expression is known to the compiler.

---

1. Except for variably modified types like VLAs.

Answer (score 9):

We know what the size of `a` is even if it is not defined in this module. `sizeof` does not tell you how much memory has been allocated for an object in this module. It tells you how much memory the object requires.

Answer (score 5):

Just because the variable is not defined in this translation unit doesn't mean the compiler doesn't know its size.  If it didn't, it wouldn't be able to read or write from it.

The `sizeof` operator is valid on any variable or complete type, and `int` is a complete type.  If on the other hand you had a forward declaration of a struct:

```
struct mystruct;
```

You couldn't calculate `sizeof(struct mystruct)` because the type is incomplete and thus the size can't be known.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns the amount of memory allocated to that `data type`.

For `int` it is `4 bytes` and not `0 byte`, hence the output

This link will help you further with the details:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sizeof-operator-c/

Comment: "_For `int` it is `4 bytes`_" Usually yes, but not always

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of your program is actually undefined:

- the format `%ld` may be inappropriate for type `size_t`, the type of the `sizeof(a)` expression. If so, the behavior is undefined. The proper format is `%zu`, but this C99 format is not always correctly supported on common targets, such as all but the most recent versions of Visual Studio.

For best portability, you should write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    extern int a;
    printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Modified this way, the program will still output the size of the `int` type (4 on your platform) and not complain about `a` not being defined. The reasons are:

- `sizeof(a)` is evaluated at compile time, from the declared type in `extern int a;`. `a` need not be defined at all. Its type is declared as `int` and `sizeof(a)` (or simply `sizeof a`) is completely equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.
- the code does not make a reference to the object `a`. The compiler will produce the executable even if `a` is not defined in one of the modules compiled and linked together.